# How do I properly handle submit events in Vue + Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, mdbootstrap

I'm learning Rails, Vue and JS and I've got a question on the proper handling of submit buttons on Rails using Vue component to validate it. I'm using mdbootstrap for the styles.

I built a form wizard which uses vee-validate for validating the fields and in some forms I want to perform some server side operations too (eg.: validate exact address with geocoding). I'm currently facing basically three issues.

1. Although I added a v-clock directive, I'm still seeing a little
   flicker every time the form wizard component gets loaded (eg.: page
   refresh).
2. I had to workaround the Rails automatic data-disable-with handling to get it working, and it looks not optimal to me, and I'd like to know if there's a better way to deal with it (I had to disable the submit event propagation and prevent default and do the disabling/enabling manually otherwise the handler from Rails UJS will receive it afterwards and disable the button forever).
3. Although the button gets enabled again, it gets brighter every time I click on it if validation fails (some handler from mdbootstrap maybe?). It happens only after I click on refresh button on the browser and I've noticed the following div is created after each click followed by an error during form validation, causing the button to become "brighter" as in a accumulated "disabled effect":

Anyone has ideas on how these issues could be solved? Thanks!

**new.html.erb:**

```
<div id="stepper">
    <div v-cloak>
        <transition-group name="fade">
            <div class="d-none d-lg-block"  key="progress_bar">
                <%= render 'forms/progress_bar' %>
            </div>
            <div id="step1" v-if="step === 1" key="step1">
                <%= render 'forms/description' %>
            </div>
            <div id="step2" v-if="step === 2" key="step2">
                <%= render 'forms/address' %>
            </div>
        </transition-group>
    </div>
</div>
```

**_description.html.erb:**

```
<template>
  <form 
    id="description-form" 
    data-vv-scope="description-form" 
    novalidate="true"
    @submit.prevent="next('description-form', $event)">

    <div class="row mb-5">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row" id="step-1">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <div class="max-height-80">
                <div class="mb-4">
                  <h4><%= t(:'step1.title') %></h4>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label 
                    for="name" 
                    class="control-label">
                    <%= t(:'step1.label.name') %>
                  </label>
                  <input 
                    id="name" 
                    name="name" 
                    type="text" 
                    class="form-control" 
                    placeholder="<%= t(:'step1.input.name') %>" 
                    v-validate="'required'" 
                    v-model="name" 
                    :class="{ 'is-invalid': errors.has('name','description-form') }" 
                    required/>
                  <div 
                    v-if="errors.has('name','description-form')" 
                    class="invalid-feedback">
                    <%= t(:'name.required') %>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label 
                    for="description" 
                    class="control-label">
                    <%= t(:'step1.label.description') %>
                  </label>
                  <textarea 
                    id="description" 
                    name="description" 
                    class="form-control" 
                    placeholder="<%= t(:'step1.input.description') %>" 
                    rows="11" 
                    v-validate="'required'" 
                    v-model="description" 
                    :class="{ 'is-invalid': errors.has('description','description-form') }" 
                    required>
                  </textarea>
                  <div 
                    v-if="errors.has('description','description-form')" 
                    class="invalid-feedback">
                    <%= t(:'description.required') %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <footer class="page-footer white fixed-bottom d-block d-sm-none z-depth-1" id="footer">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                  <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit" data-remote="true" data-disable-with="<%= wait_spinner %>"><%= t(:'btn.next') %></button>
                </div>
              </footer>
              <div class="d-none d-sm-block">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mt-2">
                  <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit" data-remote="true" data-disable-with="<%= wait_spinner %>"><%= t(:'btn.next') %></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block mt-lg-5">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

**stepper.js**

```
var element = document.getElementById("stepper");
if (element != null) {
    Vue.use(VeeValidate);
    Vue.use(VueResource);

    Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');

    const stepper = new Vue({
        el: element,
        data() {
            return {
            /**
            * The step number (starting from 1).
            * @type {Integer}
            */
            step:1,
            name:null,
            description:null
            }
        }
    },

    methods: {
        /**
        * Goes back to previous stepp
        */
        prev() {
            this.step--;
        },
        /**
        * Triggers validation of current step and goes to the 
        * next step if validation succeeds
        * @param {String} scope The step scope used for validation.
        * @param {Object} Event that triggered the next step (form submit)
        */
        next(scope, event) {
            if (event != undefined) {
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            }

            const form = event.currentTarget;
            $("button[type=submit]",form).each(function() {
                Rails.disableElement(this);
            });

            this.validateFields(scope, event);
        },
        validateFields(scope, event) {
            this.$validator.validateAll(scope).then(function (valid) {
                this.postFieldsValidation(valid, event);
            }.bind(this));
        },
        postFieldsValidation(valid, event) {

            if (valid) {
                stepper.step++;
            }

            const form = event.currentTarget;
            $("button[type=submit]",form).each(function() {
                Rails.enableElement(this);
            });

        },
        handleError(error) {
            alert(error)
        },
        submit() {

        }
    }
});
}
```

*** edit ***
for #3, I'm using a workaround for removing the div with waves-ripple class inside my button when re-enabling elements on the form.

$("div").remove("button .waves-ripple");

however, it would be nice to know the root cause for it.